# Re-use sortProperties in similar ArrayControllers

Tags: ember.js

Referring to the [TodoMVC](http://jsbin.com/AViZATE/60/edit) built in the [Ember Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-all-todos/).

In this version there are 3 `ArrayControllers` for displaying resp. all, active and completed items.

Suppose I want to sort the content of every controller on the item's title. I'd choose to define this in a base controller and let every controller extend from this:

```
Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['title']
});

Todos.TodosIndexController = Todos.TodosController.extend();
Todos.TodosActiveController = Todos.TodosController.extend();
Todos.TodosCompletedController = Todos.TodosController.extend();
```

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Based on your example I think this is the way to go. Since index, active, completed are all todo controllers inheritance makes sense.